# NVIDIA drivers for Geforce 720m on Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 13.10

I have an Asus notebook equipped with a GeForce 720m graphic card. I know that NVIDIA drivers exist (NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-331.20) but I can't install them through the tool (no drivers found) and if I try to run the script I get many errors and the whole process will stop. How can I enable those drivers? I'm getting a really poor graphic performance

Answer (score 0):

Did you try [this driver](http://www.nvidia.com/object/linux-display-amd64-319.32-driver.html)? It looks like an older version, but it's made especially for your graphics card.

Comment: That one actually bricked the whole thing and I am now getting a black screen after the login